# Erlang's equivalent of Haskell's as-patterns

Tags: list, haskell, erlang, as-pattern

How can I write in Erlang an equivalent of this Haskell snippet?

`name@(x:xs)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it with syntax like `Name=[X|Xs]`. An example usage is

```
headlist([H|T]=L) -> io:format("List (~p) with head ~p ~n",[L,H]).
```

Comment: Note that it's often more readable to put the more specific pattern to the left and the variable to the right, as in headlist([H|T]=L) -> .... This way, multiple clauses align better, and you focus first on what is being matched rather than on the extra variable.

Comment: I agree with @RichardC but just want to say that both are legal and fully equivalent with each other.

Comment: @RichardC I don't code much in erlang so I am not very familiar about the coding practices. Thanks for pointing that out.